# Property 'dataLogs' does not exist on type 'Level'

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular 2 and i am trying to set a TSMap property to a model class, and I get the following error:  Property 'dataLogs' does not exist on type 'Level'.

The model class is

```
import {DataLog} from "./datalog.model";
import {TSMap} from "typescript-map";
export class Level {
    dataLogs: TSMap<number, DataLog>;
    resultLevel: DataLog;
}
```

And inside a component class I declare a variable like this:

```
dataLogs: TSMap<number, DataLog> = new TSMap<number, DataLog>();
```

I populate the map and then on a button click i am trying to assign it to the *Level object*

```
this.levelOne.dataLogs = this.dataLogs;
```

And I got the following error:

*Property 'dataLogs' does not exist on type 'Level'.*

```
The component is the following:


import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TSMap} from "typescript-map";

import {Level} from "../../models/level.model";
import {DataLog} from "../../models/datalog.model";

@Component({
    selector: 'game-screen',
    templateUrl: './ame-screen.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./game-screen.component.css']
})
export class Game implements OnInit {
    game: Game;
    levels: Level[] = [];
    dataLogs: TSMap<number, DataLog>;
    levelOne: Level;

    constructor() {
        this.game = new Game();
        this.levelOne = new Level();
        this.dataLogs = new TSMap<number, DataLog>();
    }

    buttonA(){
        let dataLog = new DataLog();
        dataLog.hit = 1;
        this.dataLogsMap.set(this.numberOfClicks, dataLog);

        this.levelOne.dataLogs = this.dataLogs;
    } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? What is the type of `levelOne`? The error is stating that your Level class does not have the dataLogs property. Is it possible you are using a different Level class/interface? Level is a generic name for a class/interface that might be defined elsewhere in your code or external libraries

Comment: This is the declaration of levelOne -> levelOne: Level; And the only class that appears at imports is import {Level} from "../../models/level.model";

Comment: hmm, nothing stands out from what you posted. When do you receive this error? when you compile? from your IDE? If it is from your IDE, try restarting it. It may not be seeing the correct class definition.

Comment: I have added also the component above in the question. i will try. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks!! I have restarted my IDE and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: np, glad I could help!